# How to split a string and get last match in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, split, match

I have string like this

`This is ~test content ~ok ~fine.`

I want to get `"fine"` which is after special character `~` and on last position in string using jQuery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use combination of [substring()][1] and [lastIndexOf()][2] to get the last element.

```js
str = "~test content ~thanks ok ~fine";    
strFine =str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('~'));
console.log(strFine );
```

You can use [**split()**][4] to convert the string to array and get the element at last index, last index is `length of array - 1` as array is zero based index.

```js
str = "~test content ~thanks ok ~fine";    
arr = str.split('~');
strFile = arr[arr.length-1];
console.log(strFile );
```

OR, simply call pop on array got after split

```js
str = "~test content ~thanks ok ~fine";    
console.log(str.split('~').pop());
```

Comment: first method not really working with my path, keeps the last "\" in the file name.. but second is spot on. thks!

Answer (score 5):

Just use plain JavaScript:

```
var str = "This is ~test content ~thanks ok ~fine";
var parts = str.split("~");
var what_you_want = parts.pop();
// or, non-destructive:
var what_you_want = parts[parts.length-1];
```